# Ignoring/excluding fields for serialization?

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I'm using the LibGDX Json serializer and I want to exclude specific fields. I worked with JSON.NET and that was easy.

```
[NonSerialized]
public int willNotBeSerialized;
```

I cannot seem to find a way to exclude fields like this with the current JSON extension for LibGDX. So is this possible and how? Otherwise, are there libraries that can and be compatible with all LibGDX modules?

Comment: Normally you declare fields `transient`.  Does that not work?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3382

Comment: Guess transient works. How i was not able to find that will remain one of my greatest mysteries.